# SVG Gaussian Blur not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, svg, blur, gaussian

I've looked through a couple of the other posts here regarding this issue but I'm still stuck sadly. I have ended up with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#promoIMG").css({
        "filter": "blur(4px)", 
        "-webkit-filter": "blur(4px)", 
        "-moz-filter": "blur(4px)",
            "-o-filter": "blur(4px)",
        "-ms-filter": "blur(4px)",
        "filter":"url('#f1')"
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="promoIMG"><br/>
<p>asdasdasddas</p>
    <img src="excel_graph_large.png" alt="AKB" />
    </div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="100" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>


</body>
</html>
```

It seems to be working in Chrome and ie as intended, but not in Mozilla Firefox.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is just that you have a crazy hudge value.
try this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```